# How to calculate in and out time of IBM MQ in java

Tags: ibm-mq

I am calling Date() object before writing into MQ. This is way I am capturing IN time of MQ. How to calculate out time of MQ?

Comment: What do you mean by "out time"?  Are you referring to when your PUT completes and MQ does not return a exception or are you referring the time when the message is received by the application that will be reading the message?

Comment: @JoshMc I am referring to the time when the message is received by the application for example Flume

Comment: Can the receiving application log a similar "out time" by calling Date() when it receives the message?  If you are looking for the sending application to have this time then it would be good to have a return ACK message sent back from the receiving app to the sending app, I would recommend staying away from COD messages, but that is also another option.

Comment: i am not sure on the receiving part, i know it uses flume but not well aware of it.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest solution is to get an MQ message tracking solution.  There are lots available and you can find a list here: http://www.capitalware.com/mq_tools_comm.html#mqtrk

- COA is Confirmation of Arrival - when the message is put into the destination queue
- COD is Confirmation of Delivery - when the receiving application performs an MQGET

Creating a COA/COD solution to your problem is not that difficult or complicated.  I've created many SLA solutions for customers when I was a consultant that used MQ's COA/COD.

If the messages stay within the same queue manager then life is super easy.  If not, then you need to know that the COD message (not COA) is returned using the original message's UserId. So you need to plan to have the correct security permission or the COD message will land in the DLQ (Dead Letter Queue).

Find yourself a database to use - it can be your corporate one or a simple one like SQLite, H2, etc.

The first question people ask is how to tie everything together.  i.e. what key.  Simple, use the MQMD MessageId. When the application does an MQPUT, the MQMD MessageId is populated.

Second, make sure the original message has the following MQMD fields completed: replyToQueueName, replyToQueueManagerName and report.

Third, the COA and COD messages will have the original message's MessageId in their MQMD CorrelId field.

You can go with either 3 or 4 timestamps.  The extra timestamp can be the time right before you do the MQPUT.  Let's say you want 4 timestamps then:

1. Timestamp right before the MQPUT
2. Timestamp returned in the MQMD's putDateTime from the MQPUT
3. COA Timestamp returned in the MQMD's putDateTime - matching MessageId is in CorrelId
4. COD Timestamp returned in the MQMD's putDateTime - matching MessageId is in CorrelId

Simple.  Now each row in your DB has a complete SLA record for the history of that message.  You can write simple SQL to determine:

- how long it took MQ to deliver the message i.e. timestamp #4 minus
  timestamp #1 (or #2)
- how long it stayed in the queue before the receiving application pick it up i.e. timestamp #4 minus timestamp #3  - when there is finger pointing, this is an important number!!!
- when someone says 'we never got your message' - timestamp #4 is your proof

Finally, if you are expecting a response (reply) message back (assuming the original MessageId is in the CorrelId) then you could add that timestamp to the DB as a 5th timestamp.  i.e. Timestamp #5 minus timestamp #1 (or #2) would give you the round-trip time (request-response).